# Counting characters from text in XML file using Perl's split function

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, split

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ISOSpaceTaskv1.15>
<TEXT><![CDATA[
        WHERE TO GO
        In this sprawling city, the parts of Madrid of greatest
        interest to foreign visitors are remarkably compact. Viejo Madrid, the
        city of the Hapsburgs, covers a small area that extends east from the
        pitiful Río Manzanares and magnificent Palacio Real to Puerta del Sol.
        Almost all of it can be covered in a day or two, including a lengthy
        visit to the Royal Palace. The Madrid of the Bourbon dynasty, home to
        Spain’s great art museums, is the next area worthy of exploring (for
        art lovers, though, it may very well be the first). Spain’s Golden
        Triangle of Art is concentrated on the elegant but busy Paseo del
        Prado, between Puerta del Sol and Retiro Park. Those with more time in
        Madrid, either before or after side trips to the great towns of
        Castile, might explore the barrio of Salamanca, take in a bullfight, or
        visit one or more of the smaller, more personal museums, only a ride
        from the Puerta del Sol.
]]></TEXT>
<TAGS>
<PLACE id="pl0" start="66" end="72" text="Madrid" type="" dimensionality="AREA" form="NAM" domain="" continent="" state="" country="" ctv="" gazref="" latLong="" elevation="" mod="" dcl="FALSE" countable="TRUE" gquant="" scopes="" comment="" />
<PLACE id="pl1" start="47" end="51" text="city" type="" dimensionality="AREA" form="NOM" domain="" continent="" state="" country="" ctv="" gazref="" latLong="" elevation="" mod="" dcl="FALSE" countable="TRUE" gquant="" scopes="" comment="" />
</TAGS>
</ISOSpaceTaskv1.15>
```

The `start` and `end` attributes in the `<PLACE>` tags indicate the character in which the text in the `text` attribute from  starts and ends within the text contained in the `<TEXT>` tag. For example, *Madrid* starts in the 66th character and ends in the 72th character of the text in `<TEXT>`.

I want to know which are the `start` and `end` values for every word in the text contained in `<TEXT>`. For this purpose I use the next Perl code:

```
for my $tag ($doc->findnodes('ISOSpaceTaskv1.15/TEXT')){
    my $text = $tag->textContent;
    my @Text_sp = split(undef, $text);
    my $count = 1;
    foreach my $character (@Text_sp){
       print "$count\n";
       $count = $count + 1;
       ....
    }
}
```

The problem is I get `start` and `end` values that different from the ones in the xml file. For example for the first PLACE tag I get values 34 and 39. I suspect the split does not work as expected but I really do not know which the exact problem is.

Comment: What do you get when you print `$character` and `$count` together? That is `print "$character $count\n";` (in the `foreach` loop).

Comment: Your usage of `split` looks fine to me.  Try printing out the contents of `$text` to stdout and have a look at that

Comment: What's `split undef`??? That errors `Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation` and works as `split //` (which is what you actually want).

Comment: Anyway, it's not split giving you the problem. Checking `$text` and `@Text_sp` would have told you that.

Comment: Because your text contains non-ASCII characters you should put `use utf8;` at the beginning of your program (it will affect `split`'s behavior).

Comment: @Pierre, 1) Only ASCII characters are used. 2) `use utf8;` simply tells Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8. The text in question an XML file, not Perl source code. It will have no effect.

Comment: @ikegami 'í' doesn't look like ASCII to me.

Comment: @Pierre The data source is not the same as the source code.  `use utf8` only applies to the source code.

Comment: @Pierre, Ah yes, there is a "í", but it's far too deep in to the text to affect the position of "Madrid". Anyway, `textContent` already returns the text decoded. (It would make no sense to return raw XML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex search and `pos` function:

```
while( $text=~/\b([^\s,.;:!?]+)/g ) {
   my $end = pos($text);
   my $start = $end-length($1);
   print "$start-$end $1\n";
}
```

First output lines looks like this:

```
9-14 WHERE
15-17 TO
18-20 GO
29-31 In
32-36 this
37-46 sprawling
47-51 city
53-56 the
57-62 parts
63-65 of
66-72 Madrid
73-75 of
```

Seems **start** and **end** are correct, probably you will need to tune the regex to meet what you want to be "word boundry".

Comment: `my $start = $-[0]; my $end = $+[0];` is less convoluted.

Answer (score -1):

Using a regex to capture words:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use XML::LibXML;

binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => do {
    binmode DATA, ':utf8';
    local $/;
    <DATA>
});

for my $tag ($xml->findnodes('ISOSpaceTaskv1.15/TEXT')){
    my $text = $tag->textContent;
    while ($text =~ m/([^\s,().]+)/g) {
        my $word = $1;
        my $start = $-[0];
        my $end = $+[0] - 1;
        print "$start-$end <$word>\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ISOSpaceTaskv1.15>
<TEXT><![CDATA[
        WHERE TO GO
        In this sprawling city, the parts of Madrid of greatest
        interest to foreign visitors are remarkably compact. Viejo Madrid, the
        city of the Hapsburgs, covers a small area that extends east from the
        pitiful Río Manzanares and magnificent Palacio Real to Puerta del Sol.
        Almost all of it can be covered in a day or two, including a lengthy
        visit to the Royal Palace. The Madrid of the Bourbon dynasty, home to
        Spain’s great art museums, is the next area worthy of exploring (for
        art lovers, though, it may very well be the first). Spain’s Golden
        Triangle of Art is concentrated on the elegant but busy Paseo del
        Prado, between Puerta del Sol and Retiro Park. Those with more time in
        Madrid, either before or after side trips to the great towns of
        Castile, might explore the barrio of Salamanca, take in a bullfight, or
        visit one or more of the smaller, more personal museums, only a ride
        from the Puerta del Sol.
]]></TEXT>
<TAGS>
<PLACE id="pl0" start="66" end="72" text="Madrid" type="" dimensionality="AREA" form="NAM" domain="" continent="" state="" country="" ctv="" gazref="" latLong="" elevation="" mod="" dcl="FALSE" countable="TRUE" gquant="" scopes="" comment="" />
<PLACE id="pl1" start="47" end="51" text="city" type="" dimensionality="AREA" form="NOM" domain="" continent="" state="" country="" ctv="" gazref="" latLong="" elevation="" mod="" dcl="FALSE" countable="TRUE" gquant="" scopes="" comment="" />
</TAGS>
</ISOSpaceTaskv1.15>
```

Outputs:

```
9-13 <WHERE>
15-16 <TO>
18-19 <GO>
29-30 <In>
32-35 <this>
37-45 <sprawling>
47-50 <city>
53-55 <the>
57-61 <parts>
63-64 <of>
66-71 <Madrid>
73-74 <of>
76-83 <greatest>
93-100 <interest>
102-103 <to>
105-111 <foreign>
113-120 <visitors>
122-124 <are>
126-135 <remarkably>
137-143 <compact>
146-150 <Viejo>
152-157 <Madrid>
160-162 <the>
172-175 <city>
177-178 <of>
180-182 <the>
184-192 <Hapsburgs>
195-200 <covers>
202-202 <a>
204-208 <small>
210-213 <area>
215-218 <that>
220-226 <extends>
228-231 <east>
233-236 <from>
238-240 <the>
250-256 <pitiful>
258-260 <Río>
262-271 <Manzanares>
273-275 <and>
277-287 <magnificent>
289-295 <Palacio>
297-300 <Real>
302-303 <to>
305-310 <Puerta>
312-314 <del>
316-318 <Sol>
329-334 <Almost>
336-338 <all>
340-341 <of>
343-344 <it>
346-348 <can>
350-351 <be>
353-359 <covered>
361-362 <in>
364-364 <a>
366-368 <day>
370-371 <or>
373-375 <two>
378-386 <including>
388-388 <a>
390-396 <lengthy>
406-410 <visit>
412-413 <to>
415-417 <the>
419-423 <Royal>
425-430 <Palace>
433-435 <The>
437-442 <Madrid>
444-445 <of>
447-449 <the>
451-457 <Bourbon>
459-465 <dynasty>
468-471 <home>
473-474 <to>
484-490 <Spain’s>
492-496 <great>
498-500 <art>
502-508 <museums>
511-512 <is>
514-516 <the>
518-521 <next>
523-526 <area>
528-533 <worthy>
535-536 <of>
538-546 <exploring>
549-551 <for>
561-563 <art>
565-570 <lovers>
573-578 <though>
581-582 <it>
584-586 <may>
588-591 <very>
593-596 <well>
598-599 <be>
601-603 <the>
605-609 <first>
613-619 <Spain’s>
621-626 <Golden>
636-643 <Triangle>
645-646 <of>
648-650 <Art>
652-653 <is>
655-666 <concentrated>
668-669 <on>
671-673 <the>
675-681 <elegant>
683-685 <but>
687-690 <busy>
692-696 <Paseo>
698-700 <del>
710-714 <Prado>
717-723 <between>
725-730 <Puerta>
732-734 <del>
736-738 <Sol>
740-742 <and>
744-749 <Retiro>
751-754 <Park>
757-761 <Those>
763-766 <with>
768-771 <more>
773-776 <time>
778-779 <in>
789-794 <Madrid>
797-802 <either>
804-809 <before>
811-812 <or>
814-818 <after>
820-823 <side>
825-829 <trips>
831-832 <to>
834-836 <the>
838-842 <great>
844-848 <towns>
850-851 <of>
861-867 <Castile>
870-874 <might>
876-882 <explore>
884-886 <the>
888-893 <barrio>
895-896 <of>
898-906 <Salamanca>
909-912 <take>
914-915 <in>
917-917 <a>
919-927 <bullfight>
930-931 <or>
941-945 <visit>
947-949 <one>
951-952 <or>
954-957 <more>
959-960 <of>
962-964 <the>
966-972 <smaller>
975-978 <more>
980-987 <personal>
989-995 <museums>
998-1001 <only>
1003-1003 <a>
1005-1008 <ride>
1018-1021 <from>
1023-1025 <the>
1027-1032 <Puerta>
1034-1036 <del>
1038-1040 <Sol>
```